# Dynamic Content blocks inside VAWP

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

VAWP = View as Web Page

Currently we are using quite many dynamic content blocks in our emails. Mostly because of language aspects. furthermore we do a lot of automations that keep the dataextensions up to date which use the overwrite operation.

- When i send an email and take a look at the VAWP directly after the
  send everything is ok, because no automation has taken place until
  that moment.
- When i manually(!) edit the row and change the language the VAWP
  updates to the current language in that dataextension.
- When i overwrite the dataextension and change that user to a
  different language, the dynamic content on the VAWP changes to the
  default content of dynamic content blocks.

I narrowed it down to the fact that dynamic content blocks always use variables directly from the dataextension and not those from ampscripts (obviously).

```
{{#=if (([country] == "USA") && ([language] == "EN"))}}
{{= BeginImpressionRegion("02__Rule_1__USA_EN_HEADER")}}
```

Is there a way to take ampscript variables in dynamic content blocks, that content creators can still use dynamic content blocks? The main reason is that most content creators at our company are not familiar with ampscript.

Comment: The answer is to not use dynamic content blocks -- blocks that offer no flexibility for handling the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No possible solution when you dont use journey builder.

Salesforce Support admitted that its a gap in the product.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I will recommend using [Sendlog](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_logging.htm&type=5) to store the variables as they were at the time, when the emails was sent. In this way, you will be able to build your VAWP based on the data in Sendlog, and not in the Data Extension which the emails are sent to. Otherwise, VAWP will always retrieve the current state of the data in sendable DE.

Comment: I do store the variables in the SendLog dataextension and do the lookups based on the sendlog. But the main point of this question is about dynamic content blocks in VAWP. They don't use ampscript, they directly get the values of the sending dataextension. Therefore every vawp fails when the sending dataextension is updated, because the link will be destroyed since its transient. Content creators use dynamic content blocks and the current implementation of salesforce regarding dynamic content blocks is not able to deliver a solution which stays intact if the sending data extension is updated.

Comment: Yeah, I'd use a sendlog or sends to filters of DEs that never overwritten.  Journeys are a problem because the target DEs get recreated unlike traditional triggers.