# Idea: Improve dynamic content blocks (VAWP-related)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, ideas, gtl

Salesforce support told me i should create a case on stackexchange to get votes on this idea because they admitted it is an gap in product.

Here is a link to the problem:

[Dynamic Content blocks inside VAWP](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219058/dynamic-content-blocks-inside-vawp)

Copy of the idea text:

> Dynamic content blocks perform poorly on view as web page when the
> sending data extension gets updated and journey builder is not used.
> In these scenarios dynamic content blocks will always show default
> content.
>
> To change that behaviour i would like to have a third data
> source for rules of dynamic content blocks called programmatic
> variables (AMPScript / GTL / SSJS).
>
> With this addition you could
> restore the VAWP like it was at send time when you query the SendLog,
> because you can fill the variables differently when you make use of
> _messagecontext. Normally you would set variables like SET @variable = [DE_FIELD] but in _messagecontext VAWP you would fill these variables
> by LookUp on the SendLog dataextension.

Here is the link to the idea, please Upvote it:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000EAwxQAG

Comment: Great idea but isn’t this betted suited for the meta channel?

Comment: Is the meta channel inside stackexchange or inside ideas of marketing cloud? I don't know the meta channel yet.

Comment: https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Shall i create a new "question" there or put it under https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2361/ideas-that-every-salesforce-developer-should-vote-for ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why Salesforce Support would have directed you to get votes on your idea on StackExchange. I think they were referring to [IdeaExchange](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205453&type=1).

If your Idea reaches 2,500 points (or 250 votes) on IdeaExchange it will be reviewed by the respective Salesforce Product Team and an official response will be posted.

Comment: I had created some ideas and was asking how to get more upvotes because most of my ideas were in personalization builder which is very unpopular. Therefore I asked what else I can do to get votes other than collaboration: Marketing Cloud success. Support told me that they have the permission to vote aswell as that I should post this on Stackexchange.